# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null trying to delete a row

Tags: java

I have this piece of code that basically scrolls through a list, compares if the object (dimension) is present in the list and deletes it. This way I delete the relationship in my threadId_dimensionId table.

```
   public void unlink(String threatId, String dimensionId) {
    log.info("Trying to delete the relationship of Threat id: {} with dimension id: {}", threatId, dimensionId);

    Threat threat = threatService.findById(threatId);
    Dimension dimension = dimensionService.findById(dimensionId);
        threat.getDimensions().forEach(f -> {
            if (f.getId().equals(dimension.getId())) {
                threat.getDimensions().removeIf(e -> f.equals(dimension));
                threatRepository.saveAndFlush(threat);

            }

        });

}
```

The problem is that when I delete it, it throws the following exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
Note, despite the exception the relationship is being deleted.

Any suggestions on how to avoid this error?

Essa sao minhas classes

Threat

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.DETACH,
        CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.REFRESH,
        CascadeType.PERSIST
}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "threat_dimension", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "threat_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "dimension_id")})
private List<Dimension> dimensions;
```

And Dimension

```
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "dimensions", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Threat> threats;
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: In `threat.getDimensions().removeIf(e -> f.equals(dimension));`, did you mean to use the argument `e`?

Comment: You must not modify the collection while it is being iterated. You are doing exactly that: `thread.getDimensions().forEach(dim -> threat.getDimensions().removeIf(…))`

Comment: How should I do it? I have tried several ways, or does not delete and throws no exception. Or deletes and throws exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you cannot modify a collection at the same time while you are iterating over it. Also, your lambdas look a bit funky. You iterate over `getDimensions()` twice, but never use the inner lambda parameter. Always saving and flushing with each iteration sounds like a performance bottleneck, since it will create too many queries.

It should be sufficient to modify the collection once and then saving your entity (which is usually done automatically at the end of the transaction):

```
public void unlink(String threatId, String dimensionId) {
  log.info("Trying to delete the relationship of Threat id: {} with dimension id: {}", threatId, dimensionId);

  Threat threat = threatService.findById(threatId);
  Dimension dimension = dimensionService.findById(dimensionId);
  // mutate collection by removing items:
  threat.getDimensions().removeIf(dim -> dim.getId().equals(dimension.getId()));
  threatRepository.saveAndFlush(threat);
}
```